# iptables - block (wildcard-)subdomains because of bruteforce with different IP's

Tags: security, ubuntu-14.04, iptables, postfix-mta

In my /var/log/mail.log of my ubuntu 14.04-server I find a huge amount of lines like these:

```
Sep 16 13:23:03 server postfix/smtpd[25621]: warning: 212-83-162-157.rev.poneytelecom.eu[212.83.162.157]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
....
Sep 16 12:57:29 server postfix/smtpd[24828]: warning: 212-83-175-192.rev.poneytelecom.eu[212.83.175.192]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
```

So I think, someone criminal tries to log in at postfix to send spam. As you can see at every attempt the criminal uses a different IP and subdomain. So blocking by configuring iptables to block specific IP's makes no sense.
So what I want to do is to block all subdomains of the domain "poneytelecom.eu" by iptables.

Therefore I tried different things:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m string --algo bm --string "*poneytelecom.eu" -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -m string --string "Host: *poneytelecom.eu" --algo bm -j DROP
iptables –A INPUT –m string --algo bm --string "*poneytelecom.eu" -j DROP
```

The command "iptables -L -n --line" says this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "Host: *poneytelecom.eu" ALGO name bm TO 65535
2    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "*poneytelecom.eu" ALGO name bm TO 65535
3    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "*poneytelecom.eu" ALGO name bm TO 65535
```

But with that it does not work; I still can see breakin-attempts in /var/log/mail.log by this domain:

```
Sep 16 13:32:25 server postfix/smtpd[25922]: warning: 62-210-188-107.rev.poneytelecom.eu[62.210.188.107]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
```

Does anybody know, what I'm doing wrong respectively how to block subdomains by iptables?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there is smtp brute-force attack on your server. In order to avoid these kind of attack you must use fail2ban, which  supports brute-force protection for SSH, SMTP, etc.

http://techarena51.com/index.php/confiigure-fail2ban-block-brute-force-ips-scanning-postfix-logs/

Comment: I want to avoid  further software to archieve that. I wrote a bash-script, which works already pretty well with IP-addresses. This script I want to expand to listen to (sub-)domains, too, later. Therefore I need to know why the configuration of iptables for subdomains does not work like I did it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check hacker's IP address' range:

https://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/212.129.28.14

Range is **212.129.0.0/18**

Then block range:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 212.129.0.0/18 -j DROP

service iptables save
```